# Readonly filesystem benchmark software on Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, benchmarking, iozone

*Updated: `iozone` has an option `-+E` which could use non-iozone file to run a readonly FS benchmark test*

I am working on a project which aimed at making a 2level-cached read-only filesystem, and now I need to test it's performance.

I've tried `iozone`, but seems that even use `-i 1` it will also create a temp file, which I could not support.

Could you give me some advice about use `iozone` to test read-only FS? I'm really not familiar with it

Is there any benchmark software could test read-only FS?

Thanks your guys!

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend [fio](https://github.com/axboe/fio) tool. It has a lot of options that help you mimick real world scenarios. I haven't used the readonly option myself but it has the capability.